# Is there a PHP equivalent of Python's traceback.format_exc()?

Tags: python, php

In python, if an exception is thrown, you can call `traceback.format_exc()` to get a complete stack trace of the exception as a string that can be stored in a variable, as if you were debugging.

In PHP, I do have access to the exception message via `catch (Exception $e)`, but I was wondering if there were a way to get the stack trace of the line that threw the exception, as a string?

Specifically PHP 7.3 would be helpful, as this is the version of our interpreter.

Comment: you could just enable error logging in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `debug_backtrace()` will do the same in PHP

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

I hope it's helpful